# Move middle content to sidebar on desktop responsively

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create the responsive layout in the image below.

- A must remain at the top.
- B moves to a sidebar on desktop and reduces in width. (From 100% down to 1/3)
- C "moves up" to connect with the bottom of A.

I'd really prefer to avoid javascript.

I can use flexbox if needed..

[image: layouts]

And any tips for a better title for this post?

Comment: Can you create a [minimal example or snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @ludoboilon for the grid-template-areas suggestion.

```css
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  display: grid;
}
.a {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.b {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.c {
  background-color: pink;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  }

  .a {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;
  }

  .b {
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
  }

  .c {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
  }
}

span {
  font-size: 200%;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="a"><span>A</span></div>
      <div class="b"><span>B</span></div>
      <div class="c"><span>C</span><br><br><br><br><br></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Also, you can use "fr" instead of "%" or "px" or anything, for exemple:

```
.boxContainer {
      grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}
```

But probably "[grid-template-areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas)" can be helpful.

Comment: grid-template-areas had passed me by.. very neat!

Answer (score 0):

1/ Your title/question.

Maybe you want to know "how to set my responsive layout in CSS/JS ?" is it ? (I personally think you don't need JS at all in this case).

2/ Your problem.

I think you really need to use "grid" or "flexbox" to fix it.
The grid-template-areas should be a possibility, or a simple display flex with order property with media queries to adapt for each device break size.

I'm sorry, I am not english native speaker but I think you'll understand my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use css grid and media queries. Remember, that you can use pixels (px) and percents (%) to create rows and columns

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer! provide working example

Answer (score 0):

You're welcome. But I'm just thinking about the height of each box. Maybe you'll have an issue with the b box and probably should add an overflow-y: scroll; for this one. I'm curious to know about the behavior. If the scrollbar is not wanted, you can custom or remove it easily. Good Luck buddy.